# I use the WifiManager class to turn on and off wifi but it does not working

Tags: java, android, wifi, wifimanager

```
wifiOn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wifi on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});


wifiOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "wifi off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Comment: Did you see this note for `setWifiEnabled(boolean enabled)` : “This method was deprecated in API level 29.  … Compatibility Note: For applications targeting Build.VERSION_CODES.Q or above, this API will always fail and return false. “.   Source: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager